# What is the difference between different "compression" systems?

Tags: tar, compression, zip, 7zip

I've always used TAR and ZIP for compression, but recently I have heard about the `*.Z` compression algorithm. This brought up a question for me:

*With all of these compression systems, which one is best for general use and compression?*

Running a few tests, I have discovered that `tar`, as I discovered, does NOT really compress (unless explicitly specified). Meaning, what is it good for compared to other compression methods?

I am already aware that ZIP is the most widely-used compression system, but should I use it instead of `*.Z`, `*.7z`, `.tar`, or `.tar.<insert ending here>`?

Post Summary:

1. Should I use `*.tar`, `*.Z`, `*.7z`, `.tar`, or `.tar.<insert ending here>` for the best compression?
2. If plain `*.tar` doesn't compress, why do we use it?

EDIT: Not all algorithms allow storing of Linux permissions (from what I learned). Which do, and is there some sort of hack (or script) I could use to store permissions?

Comment: There's no need to say that stuff, just either pick the top voted one or the one that you found the most helpful :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`tar` stands for tape archive.  All it does is pack files, and their metadata ( permissions, ownership, etc ) into a stream of bytes that can be stored on a tape drive ( or a file ) and restored later.  Compression is an entirely separate matter that you used to have to pipe the output through an external utility to compress if wanted that.  GNU tar was nice enough to add switches to tell it to automatically filter the output through the appropriate utility as a shortcut.

Zip and 7z combine the archiving and compression together into their own container format, and they are meant to pack files on a DOS/Windows system, so they do not store unix permissions and ownership.  Thus if you want to store permissions for proper backups, you need to stick with tar.  If you plan on exchanging files with Windows users, then zip or 7z is good.  The actual compression algorithms zip and 7zip use can be used with tar, by uzing `gzip` and `lzma` respectively.

lzma ( aka. *.xz ) has one of the best compression ratios, and is quite fast at decompression, making it a top choice these days.  It does however, require a ton of ram and cpu time to compress.  The venerable `gzip` is quite a bit faster at compression, so may be used if you don't want to dedicate that much cpu time.  It also has an even faster variant called lzop.  `bzip2` is still fairly popular as it largely replaced gzip for a time before 7zip/lzma came about, since it got better compression ratios, but is falling out of favor these days since 7z/lzma is faster at decompression and gets better compression ratios.  The `compress` utility, which normally names files *.Z, is ancient and long forgotten.

One of the other important differences between zip and tar is that zip compresses the data in small chunks, whereas when you compress a tar file, you compress the whole thing at once.  The latter gives better compression ratios, but in order to extract a single file at the end of the archive, you must decompress the whole thing to get to it.  Thus the zip format is better at extracting a single file or two from a large archive.  7z and `dar` allow you to choose to compress the whole thing ( called "solid" mode ) or small chunks for easy piecemeal extraction.

Comment: But, only TAR supports metadata? Or does gzip/bzip2 also now support metadata

Comment: @pacificfils, the compression utilities only compress a single file, with no metadata.

Comment: can one tar a folder and then put that in a zip and preserve permissions though?

Comment: @pacificfils, yes, but it would be a bit silly since you would be giving up the benefits of zip, and the better compression ratio of `gzip`.

Comment: @pacificfils `tar cfp` will preserve permissions. A tar file is uncompressed, so zip (7-zip), gzip2, gzip, lzo, etc will all compress a tar file well (in general, a tar of compressed files is unlikely to be compressible).

Comment: The OP seems quite confused about the difference between archiving (combining several files/folders in file acting as a container) and compressing. Maybe you could add a first paragraph explaining it... great answer to, did not know about `dar`.

Comment: @Rmano, umm... that is pretty much exactly what my first paragraph explains.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, you seem to be just repeating my answer, unless you are trying to say you need the -p switch in order to preserve permissions, in which case, that is incorrect.

Comment: @psusi Depends on the platform, but you *might* need `p` to preserve the owner. I was commenting on your comment from 14 hours ago, not your answer generally (note I did not post an answer)!

Comment: ZIP *does* also preserve Unix attributes and permissions: The Unix `zip` and `unzip` utilities *always* store and restore Unix file permissions, `unzip` restores the Unix file timestamps unless you provide the `-DD` option, and `unzip` even restores the UID and GID if you provide the `-X` option.

Answer (score 9):

The details of the algorithms are off topic here<sup>1</sup> since they are not in any way specific to Linux, let alone Ubuntu. You will, however, find some nice info [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression).

Now on to `tar`, as you said, `tar` is not and never has been a compression program. Instead, it is an *archiver*; its primary purpose is to make one big file out of a lot of small ones. Historically this was to facilitate storing on tape drives, hence the name: Tape ARchive.

Today, the primary reason to use `tar` is to decrease the number of files on your system. Each file on a Unix file system takes up an [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode), the more files you have, the fewer inodes available and when you run out of inodes, you can no longer create new files. To put it simply, the same amount of data stored as thousands of files will take up more of your hard drive than those same files in a single tar archive.

To illustrate, since this has been contested in the comments, on my 68G `/` partition, I have the following number of total and used inodes (bear in mind that inode count depends on the file system type and the size of the partition):

```
Inode count:              393216
Free inodes:              171421
```

If I now proceed to attempt to create more files than I have inodes:

```
$ touch {1..171422}
touch: cannot touch ‘171388’: No space left on device
touch: cannot touch ‘171389’: No space left on device
touch: cannot touch ‘171390’: No space left on device
touch: cannot touch ‘171391’: No space left on device
touch: cannot touch ‘171392’: No space left on device
touch: cannot touch ‘171393’: No space left on device
touch: cannot touch ‘171394’: No space left on device
touch: cannot touch ‘171395’: No space left on device
touch: cannot touch ‘171396’: No space left on device
touch: cannot touch ‘171397’: No space left on device
```

No space? But I have loads of space:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       5,8G  4,3G  1,2G  79% /
```

As you can see above, creating a few hundred thousand empty files rapidly depletes my inodes and I can no longer create new ones. If I were to `tar` these I would be able to start creating files again.

Having fewer files also greatly speeds up the file system I/O especially on NFS mounted filesystems. I always tar my old work directories when a project is finished since the fewer files I have, the faster programs like `find` will work.

There is a [great answer](https://superuser.com/a/565974/151431) on Super User that goes into far more detail, but in addition to the above, the other basic reasons why `tar` is still popular today are:

1. Efficiency: using `tar` to pipe through a compression program like `gzip` is more efficient since it avoids the creation of intermediate files.
2. `tar` comes with all sorts of bells and whistles, features that have been designed over its long history that make it particularly useful for *nix backups (think permissions, file ownership, the ability to pipe data straight to STDOUT and over an SSH link...)
3. Inertia. We're used to `tar`. It's safe to assume it will be available on any *nix you might happen to use which makes it very portable and handy for source code tarballs.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is absolutely true and has nothing to do with the fact that I don't know enough about them to explain :)

Comment: My computer has had (in the past) upwards of 10,000,000 files, and that's not really too crazy. I never use `tar` to "reduce the number of files" since most filesystems frankly don't care, and it's not really optimal anyway since `tar` doesn't support easy random access to files. Rather, the main use (for me and I think for most folks) is to share files (e.g. source code) with other people in a simple way.

Comment: @nneonneo have you ever had to work with millions of files in a _single_ directory? I have and believe me it is not easy. Quite apart from the obvious problems with `ARG_MAX`, this can make dealing with your files in any way a hassle and can actually bring a (badly) set up network where files are stored in a central server and shared with NFS to its knees. As for reducing the number of files overall, you'll need way more files than that to notice but in multi user setups, the number of inodes can indeed become limiting.

Comment: @nneonneo to give a more concrete example, `tune2fs -l` on the partition holding my $HOME tells me I have 19,300,352 inodes. I will not be able to create more files than that. As you said, 10^6 is not crazy, not even in the higher ranges really. Depending on what you're doing you can have need of _way_ more than that.

Comment: @nneonneo see updated answer for a real world example of how you can easily run out of inodes.

Comment: My server is using just over 1 million inodes and that is only because I have a metric ton of email ( lots of high traffic mailing lists going back for years ) and store it in Maildir format.  I have no idea what you could possibly be doing to use up 19 million inodes.  You would have to create a new file every second, 24 hours a day, for over 7 months.

Comment: @psusi the number of inodes depends directly on the file system type and on the size of the partition in question (in the example above, I am showing the real numbers of a partition in a VM, as you saw, that number is quite small). Also, working on large genomics datasets (which I often do) or any kind of protein/gene annotations at the multi-genome scale can easily produce millions of files, depending on what you do. Now imagine a network with thousands of researches each of whom creates millions of files and you start building a picture. It ain't pretty, I've been there :).

Comment: I guess you formatted that filesystem with an unusual inode ratio.. my 30 GB filesystem has room for 1.9 million.

Comment: @psusi that's on a VM (and I just accepted the Ubuntu defaults) so it might play a role but it will always depend on file system type, and smaller ones will always have less. And in any case, 2 million is not that much and can easily be reached on a multiuser system. Main point is that this is one of the things that taring can protect you from, though it is indeed becoming less relevant as disks grow. It was a much more serious issue some years ago.

Answer (score 4):

There are two distinct but related tasks.  Packing a tree of files
(including filenames, directory structure, filesystem permissions,
ownership and any other metadata) into a byte stream is called
*archiving*.  Removing redundancy in a byte stream to produce a
smaller byte stream is called *compression*.

On Unix, the two operations are separated, with distinct tools for
each.  On most other platforms (current and historical) combined tools
perform both archiving and compression.

(gzip and other programs that mimic gzip's interface often have the
option to store the original filename in the compressed output, but
this, along with a CRC or other check to detect corruption, is the
only metadata they can store.)

There are advantages to separating compression from archiving.
Archiving is platform-specific (the filesystem metadata needing
preserving varies widely), but the implementation is straightforward,
largely I/O-bound, and changes little over time.  Compression is platform-independent, but implementations are CPU-bound
and algorithms are constantly improving to take advantage of the
increased resources that modern hardware can bring to bear on the
problem.

The most popular Unix archiver is `tar`, although there exist others
such as `cpio` and `ar`.  (Debian packages are `ar` archives, while
`cpio` is often used for inital ramdisks.)  `tar` is or has often been
combined with compression tools such as `compress` (.Z), `gzip` (.gz),
`bzip2` (.bz2) and `xz` (.xz), from oldest to youngest, and not
coincidentally from worst to best compression.

Making a `tar` archive and compressing it are distinct steps: the
compressor knows nothing about the `tar` file format.  This means that
extracting a single file from a compressed `tar` archive requires
decompressing all of the preceding files.  This is often called a
"solid" archive.

Equally, since tar is a "streaming" format--required for it to be useful in a
pipeline--there is no global index in a tar archive, and listing the
contents of a tar archive is just as expensive as extracting it.

By contrast, Zip and RAR and 7-zip (the most popular archivers on
modern Windows platforms) usually compress each file separately, and
compress metadata lightly if at all.  This allows for cheap listing of
the files in an archive and extraction of individual files, but
means that redundancy between multiple files in the same archive
cannot be exploited to increase compression.  While in general
compressing an already-compressed file does not reduce file size
further, occasionally you might see a zip file within a zip file: the
first zipping turned lots of small files into one big file (probably
with compression disabled), which the second zipping then compressed
as a single entity.

There is cross-pollination between the differing platforms and
philosophies: `gzip` is essentially `zip`'s compressor without its
archiver, and `xz` is essentially `7-zip`'s compressor without its
archiver.

There are other, specialized compressors.  PPM variants and their
successor `ZPAQ` are optimized for maximum compression without regard to
resource consumption.  They can easily chew up as much CPU and RAM as
you can throw at them, and decompression is just as taxing as
compression (for contrast, most widely-used compression tools are
*asymmetric*: decompressing is cheaper than compressing).

On the other end of the spectrum, `lzo`, `snappy` and `LZ4` are "light"
compressors designed for maximum speed and minimum resource
consumption, at the cost of compression.  They're widely used within
filesystems and other object stores, but less so as standalone tools.

---

So which should you pick?

Archiving:

Since you're on Ubuntu there's no real reason to use anything other
than `tar` for archiving, unless you're trying to make files that are
easily readable elsewhere.

`zip` is hard to beat for ubiquity, but it's not Unix-centric and will
not keep your filesystem permissions and ownership information, and
its baked-in compression is antiquated.  7-zip and RAR (and ZPAQ) have
more modern compression but are equally unsuited to archiving Unix
filesystems (although there's nothing stopping you using them just as
compressors); RAR is also proprietary.

Compression:

For maximum compression you can have a look at a benchmark, such as the
enormous one at http://mattmahoney.net/dc/text.html.  This should give
you a better idea of the tradeoffs involved.

You probably don't want maximum compression, though.  It's way too
expensive.

`xz` is the most popular general-purpose compression tool on modern Unix
systems.  I believe 7-zip can read xz files too, as they are closely
related.

Finally: if you're archiving data for anything other than short-term
storage you should pick something open-source and preferably
widespread, to minimize headaches later on.

Answer (score 1):

`lzo, gz, b2, lzma (.lzma2 =.xz)` are "stream" compressors: they compress a stream of byes an don't know and don't care about files, directories and metadata like permissions. You have to use an archiver like tar to bundle all that data into a stream of bytes (a tar file) and compress that with a compressor. If it is the *data* of a single file you care about, you could also feed that file alone to one of these compressors.

`Tar, cpio and pax` are archivers: they take a bunch of files and directories and encode the data and metadata in a single file. tar is the most popular and most compatible though the technical merits between the three are minimal enough that there were religious wars about it during the dawn of time.

7z and zip are compressors AND arcihvers: Then store all the data and meta data and compress it. However AFAICT, neither of them save unix permissions.

Zip uses the same algorithm as gzip called DEFLATE. 7z uses the lzma algorithm

to read a single file from a tar.gz or the like, you will need to decompress the whole gz stream till the enough of the tar file is exposed so you can extract it. Zip allows you to compress and pull out each file individually. 7z can have either behavior.

Compression ratios and speeds:
gzip and lzo have very very fast compression and decompression speeds but low compression ratios. It also does not take much memory to compress. gzip is a little slower and gives a little better compression ratio than lzo.

It is so fast, it can be faster to read a gz or lzo compressed file from the disk and decompress it on the fly instead of reading the uncompressed file directly from the disk.

LZMA (xz) gives excellent compression on general data but takes very long to compress and decompress along with taking significant amounts of memory to compress.

bz2 used to be the high compression algorithm of choice but fell out of favour as it is both slower than lzma and takes longer to compress and decompress. However for *certain* kinds of data (dna sequences, files with very large runs of the same byte etc) bzip2 can beat everything else hands down. As an example, I once had to compress a 4GB file of 1's and b2 reduced i to a few 10's of kb while lzma took some 10's of MBs if I remember correctly.

Comment: Actually lzma is pretty fast at decompressing.

Answer (score 0):

For especially large files, you can use `rzip`. It first looks at redundant data inside of 900 MB large blocks, encodes these, and then hands the data over to bzip2 (not really, but the same algorithms are used).

Effect? Much faster than `xz`, `lzma` or `bzip2`, and in my experience its compression ratio rivals that of `lzma`. It is a RAM hog, though.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rzip

Answer (score 0):

[`gzip`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip)'s compression algorithm has been the traditional best-known most-used compression algorithm a long time. ([`zlib`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zlib) is a library that implements it.)

`bzip2` was invented later and was suggested as an algorithm that frequently might give better compression ratios than `gzip` on the usual data, however, it was more slow (computation-costly) compared to `gzip`.

`bzip2` as an alternative to `gzip` has been recently mostly obsoleted by modern algorithms.

For example, `xz -0` is stated in its manpage (`man xz`) to be "sometimes faster than `gzip -9` while compressing much better".

There are also other modern algorithms that are well-suited for on-the-fly compression and decompression (apart from `gzip`) by having high throughput (speed) and hence are popular for use in the kernel for filesystem, block-device, and memory compression (but also for fast compression of normal files).

`lzo`, `lz4` and `zstd` comparison is nicely presented at https://github.com/lz4/lz4:

```
|  Compressor             | Ratio   | Compression | Decompression |
|  ----------             | -----   | ----------- | ------------- |
|  memcpy                 |  1.000  | 13700 MB/s  |  13700 MB/s   |
|**LZ4 default (v1.9.0)** |**2.101**| **780 MB/s**| **4970 MB/s** |
|  LZO 2.09               |  2.108  |   670 MB/s  |    860 MB/s   |
|  QuickLZ 1.5.0          |  2.238  |   575 MB/s  |    780 MB/s   |
|  Snappy 1.1.4           |  2.091  |   565 MB/s  |   1950 MB/s   |
| [Zstandard] 1.4.0 -1    |  2.883  |   515 MB/s  |   1380 MB/s   |
|  LZF v3.6               |  2.073  |   415 MB/s  |    910 MB/s   |
| [zlib] deflate 1.2.11 -1|  2.730  |   100 MB/s  |    415 MB/s   |
|**LZ4 HC -9 (v1.9.0)**   |**2.721**|    41 MB/s  | **4900 MB/s** |
| [zlib] deflate 1.2.11 -6|  3.099  |    36 MB/s  |    445 MB/s   |

[zlib]: http://www.zlib.net/
[Zstandard]: http://www.zstd.net/
```

So, as noted in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ4_(compression_algorithm), `lz4` "gives a slightly worse compression ratio than the `LZO` algorithm ... . However, compression speeds are similar to LZO ..., while decompression speeds can be significantly higher than LZO". Also, as seen from the table, `zstd -1` usually gives higher compression ration than `lz4` and `lzo`, but lower speed; as for decompression, `zstd -1` compressed data decompresses faster than `lzo`, but slower than `lz4`.

As seen from [the diagram](https://github.com/facebook/zstd/blob/dev/doc/images/CSpeed2.png) at https://facebook.github.io/zstd/, `zstd -3` can be a reasonable choice (if I'm not mistaken, it's the default value when using btrfs with zstd): it compresses better than `gzip` (`zlib`) in any mode, and faster.